# Reactjs how to bind value to existing input element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a html page contains the following html and include a js file

html:

```
<input type="text" name="customValue" id="customValue" value="">
```

js file:

```
    class Calc extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
      }

      render() {
        return (99)
      }   
    }
    ReactDOM.render(<Calc />, document.getElementById("customValue"));
```

So my question is how to set the customValue to 99 using reactjs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:-

HTML

```
<div id="rootDiv"></div>
```

JS

```
class Calc extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
      }

      getValue = () => {
          return 99;
      }

      render() {
        const value = this.getValue();

        return (
            <input type="text" name="customValue" id="customValue" value={value}>
        )
      }   
}

ReactDOM.render(<Calc />, document.getElementById("rootDiv"));
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it so that it helps other people as well. Thanks!!